# Is there an sql admin panel made with Django? - Django

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, django-admin

I'm using SQL Server 2005 with Django, I'm wondering if anyone has ever attempted to create an admin panel for SQL using Django.

Would be quite useful to have!

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean with admin "panel"?

Comment: I think he is looking for a PHPMyAdmin kind of panel. In any case, I don't know about such a project in django.

Comment: @Guillaume thanks! That's exactly it!

Comment: Using django I almost never need to manipulate SQL stuff. Instead I write my models and use the amazing South framework to handle migrations, thus preventing the need to ever write a single line of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [./manage.py inspectdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) from the console and it automatically generates model files. You may then add the admin files to present the data how you want it.